# Facebook apps can't save changes with blank iPhone Store ID field

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-app-settings

While trying to save the Settings page in the app developer menu in Facebook, I'm getting an error of not submitting an iPhone Store ID however it was empty already before.

The error claims "We didn't recognize the iPad Store ID you entered. " but of course, cause it still haven't been published. It used to accept the blank field and now it simply doesn't.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have an app store ID, use 0 for now to create your app. Later you can add it in the App Dashboard.